# How can I complete a PDF form with Adobe Acrobat Pro so that I can use ISO 8601 (i.e., yyyy-mm-dd) to input date field?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, date

How can I complete a PDF form with Adobe Acrobat Pro so that I can use ISO 8601 (i.e., `yyyy-mm-dd`) to input date field?

By default, it's `mm-dd-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yy`:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `Form Editing` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>), right click the field and click `Properties`.

[image]

[image]

Click the `Format` tab, then choose `Date` from the dropdown.

You can then select `yyyy-mm-dd` from the list.

[image]